# How do I create an efficient and secure way of signing users in?

Tags: security, node.js, authentication, https, socket.io

Currently, I'm developing a socket.io-based chat that runs off an **HTTPS** Node.js server. I've successfully finished the correct steps for creating a self-signed certificate to run the server on. I want to implement a login system that's CPU and RAM efficient and preferably doesn't use any extra Node.js modules.

Currently, this is how I have my user database set up:

1. On server start-up, the server reads and stringifys a JSON file that contains the user data and load the array into the memory. A sample of the database looks like so:`[{"user":"username", "pass":"password", "id":"23a45b"}]`
2. When "/login.html" is sent an HTTP POST request from a login form, the server preforms this FOR loop, where `postdata` is the HTTP POST and `userdata` is the user database:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {
               if (postdata.user === userdata[i].user) {
                   if (userdata[i].pass === postdata.pass) {
                       res.writeHead({"Set-Cookie":"chat_user=" + userdata[i].user}, {"Set-Cookie":"chat_id=" + userdata[i].id});
                   }
               }
           }
   ```
3. When the user wants to send a message via socket.io, they'd send the message along with their username and ID. Another FOR loop would search the user database and cross-check the ID and username to make sure they match. This would happen *every time* a message was sent.

Does the following system sound efficient and secure? What things can I improve and change? My concern is that keeping an *entire* user database in the memory would be too much for a simple server, and that the CPU could be doing more useful things then checking a database every time a message is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first concern with your code is that it implies the passwords are stored in clear text in your JSON file. Please don't do that, it's a security disaster waiting to happen. If someone hacks your application and gets a hold of your JSON file, they will have the logins and the passwords of every user, and if you also store the email address of a user (as the login for instance), the attacker can then try to hack your users' email accounts (since a lot of people use the same password everywhere).

You should store the passwords in *digest* form, by applying a cryptographic hash function like SHA-1 on them (with added salt!). Read more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) or [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Secondly, to answer your question about efficiency, why not use a real database instead of a JSON file? I understand you may have simple needs to start with, but in the long run, you will surely benefit from having a more robust way to store and retrieve your data. What happens to your JSON file if you need to add a new user, or delete one? Won't you need to stop your server and reload the data? If you really want to go with an in-memory list of users, you should have a more direct way of accessing a record than looping over the entire set every time. You could build a hashtable for instance :

```
var usersHash = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {
    usersHash[userdata[i].user] = i;
}
```

This builds a simple index on your users' table, allowing you to directly access the record like so :

```
var user = userdata[usersHash[postdata.user]];
```